# Do autoboxing and unboxing behave differently in Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, autoboxing

I am manually converting code from Java (1.6) to C# and finding some difficulty with the behaviour of primitives (int and double). In C# it appears that almost all conversions happen automatically

```
        List<double> list1 = new List<double>();  // legal, C#
        double d0 = 3.0;
        list1.Add(d0);                            // legal, C#
        Double dd = 2.3f;                         // legal, C#
        list1.Add(dd);                            // legal, C#
        List<Double> list2 = new List<Double>();  // legal, C#
        double d1 = 3.0;
        list2.Add(d1);                            // legal, C#
        list2.Add(2.0);                           // legal, C#
        double d2 = list2.get(0);                 // legal, C#
```

but in Java only some are allowed

```
        List<double> list1 = new ArrayList<double>();  // illegal, Java
        List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>();  // legal, Java
        double d1 = 3.0;
        list2.add(d1);                                 // legal, Java
        list2.add(2.0);                                // legal, Java
        double d2 = list2.get(0);                      // legal, Java
```

I'd be grateful for a systematic analysis of the differences and any underlying rationale.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your C# example there is no boxing or unboxing (and autoboxing) happening. `double`  is just an alias for the `struct` `Double`.

In Java, the boxing is necessary. Because of [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you can't create a `List<double>`, only `List<Double>`. At compile time, `List<?>` becomes `List<Object>` and boxing/unboxing will need to take place so you can add a native type variable to a `List<Object>` or assign a native variable to an element of the List.

Comment: I was under the impression that List<Double> existed long before Type Erasure in Java, or am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: @RHSeeger, List<T> is a generic Type. Generics in Java where/are implemented with Type Erasure. So this implies that List<Double> didn't existed before Type Erasure (at least with the Type parameters). Notice that, List<T> will be translated to the raw type List.

Answer (score 20):

In C#, `double` and `Double` are **exactly** the same thing (as long as you haven't created your own type called `Double`, which would be stupid).

`double` is *defined* as an alias to `global::System.Double`. As such, there is no boxing here.

In java, `Double` is a boxed `double`, with type-erasure being a key part of the generics implementation.