# In Javascript, global variable is not changing value inside a function

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 1;

function b() {
    function a() {}; // local scope
    a = 10; // global scope
}
b();
alert(a);
```

It alerts 1 and not 10. I am wondering why is it so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057649/function-and-variable-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is the same as this:

```
var a = 1;

function b() {
    var a = function () {}; // local scope
    a = 10;
}
b();
alert(a);
```

Thus, the declaration of your local scope function creates a new local variable named `a` that initially has a function assigned to it, but you then reassign it to the value of `10`.  The higher scoped `a` is not touched by this inner assignment.

If the outer `a` definition is in the global scope, then you could assign to it with:

```
 window.a = 10;
```

If it is not in the global scope, then it has been "hidden" by the inner definition of `a` and there is no way to reach the outer `a` directly from the inner scope.

Answer (score 7):

A function name and a variable are essentially the same thing in Javascript. You can declare a function via:

```
var a = function () {};
```

Which is the same as `function a() {}` for most intents and purposes. Both create a *symbol* in the current scope and make that symbol's value a function.

What you're doing is you're shadowing the global `a` with your own local `a`. It makes no difference whether this local `a` was defined via `var a` or `function a`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is different from other languages:

> JavaScript® (often shortened to JS) is a lightweight, interpreted,
>   object-oriented language with first-class [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

What is `first-class`?

> [allows functions to be passed around just like any other value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178068/what-is-a-first-class-citizen-function)

So as [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) pointed out it converts the function into a variable locally in the function thus not changing the global variable.