# Is it possible to pass an arbitrary function as parameter in Javascript where function is defined at runtime?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function like

```
function myFunction1 ( myFunction2ReturnBool ){
    if (myFunction2ReturnBool()) {
         // Do something if myFunction2ReturnedBool() returned true. 
    }
}
```

Here, `myFunction2ReturnBool()` is a function that checks if a condition is fulfilled. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: what about that code doesn't work? It looks like it should work the way you have it written.

Comment: Oh okay. I wasn't sure if I can just add the () in front of an argument.

Comment: Yes, in javascript functions are [first class citizens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178068/what-is-a-first-class-citizen-function).

Comment: This is done all the time in JS, it's how callback functions work.