# First Class Objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, first-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are first-class objects in Java and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599176/what-are-first-class-objects-in-java-and-c)

Now I heard that First class objects in java are objects created without using the new keyword like String

Now we declare Arrays also without without new keyword ? so are they first class 
So i got this article http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaArraysShouldBeFirstClassObjects

Now another interesting article i found is
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaExceptionsAreFirstClassObjects
so are exceptions first class objects ??

So can anyone please define a first class object in simple manner 
&
tell me all the First Class objects in java

---

***EDIT:***

Before marking as possible duplicate please read the question carefully
Let me put it in short
My question is

1.Are arrays and Exceptions first class objects ?
and 
2.Can you define First class objects (interview type) ?

Comment: I'm not sure that "first class object" == "created without using new"...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599176/what-are-first-class-objects-in-java-and-c

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the [link at that same site](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FirstClass) just about cover it? Keep in mind that a "first-class object" is not something defined by any kind of specification and it means different things in different contexts. The c2.com site defines its own meaning, but those other examples you mention use it in a different sense. It's confusing you and rightly so because you are made to compare apples and oranges.