# giving a null value to a int type variable

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I have been searching for 2 days how to accomplish this and still have not figured it out. In my if statement I need to ensure that if a user just presses enter with out entering a value a message will prompt for re entry, also if the user enters a value less than 1. Below is a snip of my code.
I have read the int cant except null, and I have tried Integer , BUT my code wont run with that

```
int numberOfCars = -1
while (numberOfCars == null || numberOfCars < 1)
{
    numberOfCars = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of cars."));
    if(numberOfCars == null || numberOfCars < 1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a value.");
    }
}
```

Comment: How likely is an explicit `int` to equal an empty string or `null`?

Comment: There is no way whatsoever for `numberOfCars` to equal the empty string _or_ to equal null.  No way at all, for any `int` variable.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504064/does-java-allow-nullable-types

Comment: why does this make sense to you: numberOfCars == "" when number of Cars is an int

Comment: You never assign a value to numberOfCars - it will always be `-1`

Comment: just fixed that typo

Answer (score 1):

```
int numberOfCars = -1;
do {
     String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of cars.");
     if (answer != null && answer.matches("-?[0-9]+")) {
        numberOfCars = Integer.parseInt(answer);
        if (numberOfCars < 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value must be larger than 1.");
        }
     } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value not a number.");
     }
} while (numberOfCars < 1);
```

This does a validation (`matches`) as otherwise `parseInt` would throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Regular expression `String.matches(String)`

```
.matches("-?[0-9]+")
```

This matches the pattern:

- `-?` = a minus, optionally (`?`)
- `[0-9]+` = a character from `[ ... ]`, where 0-9 is range, the digits, and that one or more times (`+`)

See also [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for info on regex.

```
Integer.parseInt(string)
```

Gives an `int` value taken from the string. Like division by zero this
can raise an error, a NumberFormatException.

Here a do-while loop would fit (it rarely does). A normal while loop would be fine too.

Comment: It would be more helpful to the OP if you explained `Integer.parseInt()` and `matches()` along with the applied regex because he/she is a beginner. Or provide a link to a reputable resource

Answer (score 1):

the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` will return you a `String`. You can use a `try-catch` statement to check wether the input value is correct when you try to parse it to `int` using `Integer.parseInt()`. This will work for all of your cases.

So this could work:

```
int numberOfCars = -1;

while(numberOfCars < 1){
  try{
    numberOfCars = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of cars.");

    if(numberOfCars < 1){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a value.");
    }

  }catch(NumberFormatException e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter numeric value.");
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly ! The lack of the catch exception was what caused the errors